# What type of puzzles do I like?

Tags: cipher

### Zeur Tdconprziies

- Stevia rebaudiana (17)
- Predictable (4)
- Kirby (6)
- Tetromino minesweeper (3)

And a mixture of:

*fort to is "Word*

Hint:

> Words in bold are anagrams

Hint 2:

> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble (4) = Terrible

Answer (score 2):

I think that you like

> Mathematics Puzzles

**Zeur Tdconprziies**

> is an anagram of **Uzer Descriptionz**.
>  The point being that each clue refers to the bio on a user profile.

Stevia rebaudiana (17)

> I'm not absolutely sure but I think this refers to [Stiv's profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) and the 17th word here is **I**. (provided you consider ASP.NET as a single word).

Predictable (4)

> This refers to [my profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino) where the 4th word is **love**

Kirby (6)

> This refers to [Bubbler's profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71652/bubbler) and the 6th word in the bio is **mathematics**

Tetromino minesweeper (3)

> This refers to [bobble's profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble) where the 3rd word is **puzzles**

Putting this altogether we have

> **I love mathematics puzzles**

Comment: Any idea what the *fort to is "Word* line refers to?

Comment: @Stiv That part I've not figured out yet, I'm afraid.

Comment: If this is the intended answer, then this puzzle could be invalidated very easily if any of the linked users update their profiles.

Comment: Found the [relevant meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6834) saying that you should be very careful using Stack Exchange information that could potentially change in the future as a basis for your puzzle.

Comment: @hexomino A hint for you: What have recently passed?